# Using WireShark to sniff network traffic of an Android device connected to a PC

Tags: mqtt, wireshark

I have an Android device connected to my macbook via USB. The Android device is connected to a WiFi network, the same WiFi network that my macbook is connected to.

I wish to sniff network traffic going to the Android device (using WireShark). I then wish to filter that traffic by the MQTT protocol.

So far, I have tried doing this by running `adb shell ip addr` from my mac terminal in order to get the ip address of the `wlan0` network. I took the `inet` address and plugged the ip address into the display filter on WireShark like so:

`ip.addr == 192.168.190.123`

However, no traffic is showing on there, nothing through MQTT protocol or any other protocol, but the device is definitely making network calls.

I am incredibly naive to network stuff, so I really feel lost. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Sounds like your WiFi AP is enforcing device separation so no too devices can see traffic for any other device.